# How to change single target entity into list using Telethon module in Python

Tags: python, list, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to write a script that can send a message to Telegram groups. I can only manage to send to one group at the moment, and when I try to add a list, it doesn't work. Here is the code that I have so far, and the entity I want to create a list of is the channel IDs

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChannel
from telethon.tl import types, functions
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendMessageRequest

api_id = xxxxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('user', api_id, api_hash).start()
channel = InputPeerChannel = -123456


async def main():
    await client.send_file(channel, 'imgurl.jpg', caption="It's me!")



with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: standard rule: if you have `list` then use `for`-loop.

Comment: I don't see any list in your code. Better show code which makes problem.

Comment: Because I don't know which code to use as the entity. I tried just inputting inputPeerChannel = [group_id] but that did not work

Comment: you should show `inputPeerChannel = [group_id]` in your question. We can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question (not in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard rule: if you have `list` then use `for`-loop.

```
InputPeerChannel = [-123456]

async def main():
    for channel in InputPeerChannel:
        await client.send_file(channel, 'imgurl.jpg', caption="It's me!")
```

Comment: thank you this was exactly what I was missing, the "for channel in InputPeerChannel" was what I didn't realize I needed. Thank you!